# Why is the CSVT file changing my real values to null?

Tags: qgis, data, csv, metadata

I made a CSVT file to change desired real data to string data. After importing the original CSV file, that was linked by file name to the CSVT file, the string data appears as normal however all the real data has been replaced with NULL values! Why is this happening?

With in the CSVT I have made sure there are no spaces, and I have also made sure the file name is exactly the same as the CSV. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: perhaps you could post a couple of samples lines from the csv, plus the csvt line?

Answer (score 2):

You should convert/export your tabular data to .DBF instead of CSVT.

I tried to do this CSVT thing and it was a big pain and the results weren't great.

Instead, I exported my tabular data out of LibreCalc / OpenOffice Calc to a .DBF table.

I then added that to QGIS through the add vector layer (yes vector layer) dialogue - be sure to change data type to "All Files"

Sure enough, it read all the field formats spot on...I was off and running!